# How do you say "taupe" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've searched through several dictionaries but the closest I've gotten is taupo, and I'm not sure if that's a real Esperanto word.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify, whether this is about the [(group of) color(s) called "taupe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taupe) or about some other meaning of the English word.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the color, you could use `talpa`, since it comes from the animal. That's what Italian does, for example.

Depending on the needs of the context, you might want to use another adjective, such as `helbruna`, `bruneca` aŭ eĉ `bruna` for the light taupe, or `grizeca` for taupe grey. Taupe by itself does not longer [refer to a single color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taupe).

If you need to stick to taupe, then you can go for `heltalpa`, `griztalpa`, ...

Comment: To add to this: Wells gives _talp(kolor)a_.